# Is there anyway for me to create windows 8 apps(for PC and Mobile devices) on mac

Tags: windows, macos, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I use Mac OSX. I now want to try and develop an app on windows 8 for the Imagine Cup.
But i dont want to switch back to windows.
Is there any way to develop apps for windows 8 from mac?

Preferably free option....

Comment: and the tools are free anyway, but via DreamSpark you'd have access to a higher tier of the development tools :)  Be aware too that building for PC and Mobile are two different things with different tools and different (but converging) development paradigms

Answer (score 1):

The only available way is to use Virtual Machine because one cannot develop Windows 8 Modern UI app(Windows Store app) even with lower version of windows than windows 8. There are many virtual machines are available for free. [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) maybe a good start.

www.techspot.com/guides/503-windows-8-virtual-machine ,A Tutorial to create vm of windows 8.

Assuming that windows phone is the platform you chose to develop app, again you need windows to create windows phone app.

Kick start your windows phone app development  [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) .

Answer (score 1):

I actually use VMWare on a Mac to do all of my Win32 development on Windows 7 and VS2010.

You will need:

1. a powerful mac (i7)
2. lots of RAM (I have 8G, I wish I had 16G)
3. a 7200rpm HDD or SSD.

With that, it's really great for me.  I've been doing this for a few months now without a single kernel panic or blue screen at all.

Note: You cannot really develop for WP7 using this sort of configuration. The WP7 simulator uses VirtualBox, which either runs extremely slowly or not at all in other VMs, based on our experience.  Will need a real Windows machine for that ^_^

It's a workable scenario.  Good luck!